# Customizing collection views and creating space between the collection view’s cells

Tags: ios, swift

I’m trying to create this relationship that the pictures below depict of Parent -> Children -> Children -> etc. . . I’m trying to use a vertical collection view for the Parent collection view and then nested horizontal collection views for the children. But I’m struggling with moving the collection views cells down when the “View Children Button” is clicked.  I thought I could do something like this when the button is clicked:

```
@IBAction func showChildrenBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    collectionView.contentInset.bottom = 200
    collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

but this doesn’t seem to do anything. Does anyone know how to add empty space inside the collection view so that I could then create a horizontal collection view to hold the children elements.

These are some mock images of the behavior I'm trying to achieve:

Step 1)
[image]

Step 2)
[image]

Step 3)
[image]

Step 4)
[image]

Step 5)
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Easiest way , use [insertItems(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618097-insertitems)

Comment: If I do it that way will the inserted item that needs to be a horizontal collection view span two columns? How do I control the size of the newly inserted collection view?

Comment: What do you meant by **horizontal collection view span two columns**. Add your data structure, how your data formation is like. I will explain according.

Comment: Like the pictures shown above, I'm trying to create the relationship of Parent Children.   Parent -> Has many Children -> then each one of those Children can also have many Children, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take all the view as collection view.
When ViewchildrenButton get tapped, delegate it to the parent collection view controller class, and there

```
if let flowLayout = metaMoreCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

This will call the

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

and give the updated size there.